# Cannot boot laptop after copying partitions to new HDD

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I changed the HDD of my laptop for an SSD. It is a Dell XPS 15, that came with Windows, on which I installed Ubuntu, and has been working for 3 years.

The HDD was setup with several partitions, including sda5 (/) and sda7 (/home).

I created the partition table with gdisk (GPT), and I copied the partitions / and /home into the SSD sbd2 (new /). The partition sdb1 is configured with 1 MB for BIOS.

Then I booted on CD-ROM to install grub. No error. Run update-grub. OK.

When booting, I can see: "Operation System not found". There's no typo, it's actually written Operation System (not operating system).

I then started again with the CD-ROM, and installed and run boot-repair. It does its stuff, no error reported, and asked to restart. The info is http://paste.ubuntu.com/12093343/

But I still have the same message "Operation System not found". Any idea?

Comment: If all else fails, do a clean install , get SATA to USB connector, and simply copy over your personal files. Reinstalling programs and migrating data might take time, but that's the simplest solution.

Comment: @Serg Do you think it could work, if after install I copy all files, I mean all files recursively from / from the old install to the new one?

Comment: I'd avoid copying everything, just the stuff from your `/home/username` folder. If you try to copy over old `/etc` to replace new one, you might run into a problem, most likely with `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, and `/etc/fstab` files, but there's many other config files,too.   The way I'd do it, is to connect the old drive, mount it, and run `rsync` command to copy over everything form old home directory to somewhere in the new directory, like `/home/username/oldstuff` .

Comment: I don't like the idea of copying to $HOME/oldstuff. Especially for all the personnal configuration files in ~/.* directories and files. A want to keep them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

- You claim that you copied both `/` and `/home` partitions, but the new disk has just one Linux filesystem partition. This can work if you did a file-level copy (with `cp`, `tar`, or something similar); *however:*

  - At a minimum, you must adjust `/etc/fstab` and your boot loader configuration for the new setup. The boot loader changes should be handled by Boot Repair, but I don't know offhand if it will adjust `/etc/fstab`, and it looks from your output as if it has *not* been updated. This won't explain your primary problem, but you'll have to deal with it sooner or later.
  - You must be careful when doing a file-level copy to get permissions and ownership right on the new filesystem. If the permissions are wrong, the system might not boot; or it might boot but misbehave in any number of ways. Again, this issue won't explain your current problem, but you must be aware of it. See the second half of [this page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_copy_a_Linux_installation) for information on how to use `tar` to copy a Linux installation.
- Your partition numbers make me suspicious that your first installation may have used the [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://code.launchpad.net/~rodsmith/refind/master) partitioning system; but your new installation uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) Your current system is set up to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. In theory, this should work; but in practice, some motherboards have problems booting in BIOS mode from GPT disks. If I'm right about this being a problem, there are a number of fixes:

  - These problems can usually be worked around by setting the "boot flag" on the MBR's type-0xEE partition. Note that setting the "boot flag" on any partition using `parted` or GParted will ***not*** do this. You must use `fdisk` (in Ubuntu 14.04 or earlier) or set the "pmbr_boot flag" on the *whole disk* with `parted` or GParted. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) for more on such problems.
  - If your firmware is new enough (newer than about mid-2011), it's probably an EFI, not a BIOS, and in this case it may be better to install an EFI boot loader for Linux. One easy way to test this is to prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R with my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) If you can boot with that, then you can install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package -- but you'll need to create an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) on your disk first.
  - You can switch from GPT to MBR partitioning on your disk. You can convert in-place by using `gdisk`, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) You'll then need to re-install GRUB to the disk.

Personally, I wouldn't try to combine separate root (`/`) and `/home` partitions into one partition; a separate `/home` partition has clear advantages that you'll be throwing away by combining the two. Depending on your disk sizes, you might be better off using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to copy your disk; but IIRC, Clonezilla can't handle copying from a bigger to a smaller partition, so it may not be an option, at least not for the whole disk. (You might be able to use Clonezilla to copy your root partition and then copy `/home` with `cp` or `tar`, though.)

Comment: The problem was the GPT. I wiped the new disk, and setup as ms-dos partition table. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Note that is is possible to copy (cp -a) all of / from a / partition, and then all of /home to the same partition (in /home directory, of course). System works perfectly. Just /etc/fstab to change.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the /etc/fstab file on the SSD.  It still has the old hard disk partitions, and even a swap partition which you no longer have.  Nothing else looks bad to me, the UUIDs are all correct.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's one of the things I'll have to do. But I'm not there yet ! I first have the computer to recognize there's an OS on the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

I support a few computers that have Windows 7 and ubuntu on them. When I replace a hard drive I use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) to make an image and restore it to the new drive. I use [Gparted](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/) to resize the partition(s) and flag the boot partition if needed.

If I am going to a smaller drive I resize the partition(s) first if needed then make image. When I restore to the new drive I use the ignore size option in Clonezilla. If the dive I am going to is larger I resize after I have restored the image to the larger drive.

There are other methods of doing this however,this method has not failed me yet. With that said, I have not tried this with a SSD drive yet.

Comment: That's also how I usually proceed. However, here the SDD is half the HDD. Therefore, I didn't want to copy the Windows portition, neither the Dll restore blah blah stuff. Just Linux / and /home.